# How to chain two http requests in Guzzle

Tags: php, guzzle6, guzzle

I have 2 http requests

1. create a new list via mailchimp api (a list id will be created)
2. add a new member to the newly created list.

I am a bit confused about the syntax on chaining them together.
Full code below. Is it the right way to do it?

```
<?php

// auto load
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request;

// opt
$option = array(
  'base_uri' => "https://us12.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/",
  'auth' => ['apikey', '292bae37c631ac3ba03ed0640b44e6c3'],
);

// client
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client($option);

// data for a new list
$data_list = array(
  "name" => "test_mailchimp",
  "contact" => array(
    "company" => "MailChimp",
    "address1" => "675 Ponce De Leon Ave NE",
    "address2" => "Suite 5000",
    "city" => "Atlanta",
    "state" => "GA",
    "zip" => "30308",
    "country" => "US",
    "phone" => "12345678",
  ),
  "permission_reminder" => "You're receiving this email because you signed up for updates.",
  "use_archive_bar" => true,
  "campaign_defaults" => array(
    "from_name" => "test",
    "from_email" => "test@test.com",
    "subject" => "test_subject",
    "language" => "en",
  ),
    "notify_on_subscribe" => "",
    "notify_on_unsubscribe" => "",
    "email_type_option" => true,
    "visibility" => "pub",
);


// member data
$data_member = array(
  'email_address' => 'member@member.com',
  "status" => "subscribed"
);



// common
$headers = array(
  'User-Agent' => 'testing/1.0',
  'Accept'     => 'application/json'
);



// ------------- create a list -------------------
// $data should match up the field, no json =>
$url_display_list = 'lists';
$req_create_list = new Request('POST', $url_display_list, $headers, json_encode($data_list));

// promise
$promise_create_list = $client
  ->sendAsync($req_create_list)
  ->then(function ($res) use ($headers, $data_member, $client) {
    $obj = json_decode($res->getBody());
    $list_id = $obj->id;

    // --------- add a member to list ---------
    $url_create_member = 'lists/'. $list_id. '/members';
    $req_create_member = new Request('POST', $url_create_member, $headers, json_encode($data_member));

    $promise_create_member = $client
      ->sendAsync($req_create_member)
      ->then(function ($res) use ($list_id) {
        $obj = json_decode($res->getBody());
        $member_id = $obj->id;

        echo "\n--- list id ----\n";
        echo "\n". $list_id. "\n";

        echo "\n--- member id ----\n";
        echo "\n". $member_id. "\n";

        // ------------ update a member ---------


      });

  });


$promise_create_list->wait();
$promise_create_member->wait();
```

Answer (score 5):

To create a chain of actions you just need to return a new promise from `->then()` callback.

```
$finalPromise = $client->sendAsync('POST', $url1)->then(function (Response $response1) use ($client) {
    // Do something with the first response and prepare the second query.

    $secondPromise = $client->sendAsync('POST', $url2)->then(function (Response $response2) {
        // Decode JSON and/or do other stuff with the final results.

        return json_decode($response2->getBody()->getContents(), true);
    });

    return $secondPromise;
});

// The decoded JSON from the second query here.
$response2 = $finalPromise->wait();
```

Or you can use a coroutine style (it less known, but more readable, I would say):

```
// The decoded JSON from the second query here.
$response2 = coroutine(function () use ($client) {
    $response1 = (yield $client->sendAsync('POST', $url1));

    // Do something with the first response and prepare the second query.

    $response2 = (yield $client->sendAsync('POST', $url2));
    // Decode JSON and/or do other stuff with the final results.

    // The final return value of the coroutine.
    yield json_decode($response2->getBody()->getContents(), true);
});
```

Comment: I am using PHP 7.0.15 cli, It seems there is no coroutine. Do I need to install anything?

Comment: Nope, coroutines is a part of Guzzle library (it's a usual function). Just use it as `\GuzzleHttp\Promise\coroutine()` or import it (`use function GuzzleHttp\Promise\coroutine`).